# What is fast way of developing project in PHP?

Tags: php, performance

I am Java Developer. But, I am required to develop & submit a sample project of PHP (Online Shopping Management). This is just for learning basic programming in PHP.

I have been using w3schools as well.

Please kindly suggest a very easy & fast way to get confidence over the language for this development.

EDIT : Basically, I need to know the way how do I shift to PHP development from Java ?

Comment: reading source code of other projects helps me best to get a feeling of a programming language.

Comment: take a look at a sophisticated and good documented project, Zend framework for example, as a JAVA Developer you shouldn't have a Problem

Comment: if it was easy to be good it wouldn't be programming... (I'm wondering how long it will take to people panic for seeing a w3s reference?)

Comment: Thanks. I need to be habitual to this !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you are already a developer grab a framework (zend, symfony etc), go through basic tutorials on frameworks manuals and start shooting the code.

to get the good reference on e-commerce based on top of zend you might wan't to explore the guts of Magento that's available from http://www.magentocommerce.com

Answer (score 0):

I think You need to develop Online Shopping Cart using PHP-MySQL

Please go through these links, they help you understand PHP and also develop shopping cart while you learn.

```
Part 1: http://www.insanelyart.com/tutorial.php?id=168
Part 2: http://www.insanelyart.com/tutorial.php?id=170
Part 3: http://www.insanelyart.com/tutorial.php?id=172
```

Hope this helps You

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with the magento suggestion, you do not want to get bogged down with irrelevant things and  you want a large catalogue of examples to work with so implementing and extending Magento sounds like a great place to start.